# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS Power Mac G5 Booting loop

Tags: boot, 16.04, powerpc, ubuntu-mate

I'm a happy owner of Power Mac G5 dual 2,3Ghz (PowerMac 11,2) and I'm trying to install newest version of Ubuntu Mate. Installation goes well, whether I have a second partition with Mac OS or not, but after successful installation and rebooting, I'm stucked on booting menu. I can see the list of booting devices (type "l" for linux, "c" for CDROM"), but whatever I do, the distro doesn't boot up, just keeps rebooting. 
I've already tried mounting sda3, checked the yaboot.conf as well. 
Everything just seems to be ok, so what's the problem?

What should I do, or what do I do wrong?

PS: I've also tried with Lubuntu 16.04 and got exactly the same problem. 
Actually nothing newer than 12.04 LTS wants to boot up...

Comment: I don't see a PowerPC version of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: There is for Ubuntu MATE and Lubuntu, but both of them seem to not willing to cooperate with me

Comment: Is this the problem you have also experienced? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaboot/+bug/1400030 regards, Matevz

Comment: I also had the same problem. I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 and wrote it on a bootable usb. Then, it started booting from USB. However, system booting process was in the loop. What is more, I could enter a command while booting.
Here is what I commanded.
I just simply typed > HELP After "boot:" report. Then, the loop stopped and Ubuntu started. Try this way

Comment: I would try cli at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing off of USB drive.  It works well for me.  First, download the last [PPC Ubuntu-MATE here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.10/release/ubuntu-mate-16.10-desktop-powerpc.iso).  Make sure the .iso is on your desktop.

In Mac OS X, run:

```
diskutil list
```

After this, find the number of your flash drive, e.g., disk, disk2, disk3, or disk7, you never know so run this and look for the flashdrive's brand next to the BSD identifier.  (If you cannot access, Mac OS X, then insert the OS X CD/DVD with command-C and open a Terminal from within the install OS.)

Then, still within the Terminal, execute this command to format your flash drive and lose all the information (where disk# = disk3 or disk7 or whatever the above shows you):

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Test disk#

sudo dd if=/Users/<usernamenobraces>/Downloads/<nameofisofile> of=/dev/disk# bs=16m && sync
```

Here is an example with user name tom and disk3

```
sudo dd if=/Users/tom/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-16.10-desktop-powerpc.iso of=/dev/disk3 bs=16m && sync
```

You might find this fails, so if your disk identifier is 3 like the example, run this command first:

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk disk3
```

Use -f if you have trouble, then run this command again (make sure to wait until the drive is fully written to):

```
sudo dd if=/Users/tom/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-16.10-desktop-powerpc.iso of=/dev/disk3 bs=16m && sync
```

Once, this is done, restart the G5 with the flash drive inserted and press commadn-option-f to enter open firmware.  Upon entering Open Firmware, enter the following:

```
boot usb0/disk@1:2,\\yaboot
```

If that does not work, enter the following:

```
boot usb1/disk@1:2,\\yaboot
```

(If neither of those work, try again after taking the USB out and putting back in (no matter what do this once - *trust me*). Or, adjust the command in open firmware by increasing the usb# to usb3, usb4, etc.  There is one for every USB port and they do not increase by USB port #, but by device number, so there can be a skip.  Usually, it is usb1 or usb2.)

Once you get to the yaboot prompt, enter `install` or simply press enter at the Yaboot bootloader screen that follows.  If you have an old graphics card the enter `videoof=only` or `cli` or `cli-expert` and then press enter. Whether you chose graphical or text, follow the steps for a normal / default install after tat (which can be found elsewhere).  I wrote this from my G5 which is running 16.04.2, but I have used 16.10 on this machine as well prior to this.  Screenshot below:

[image]

@oemb1905

These instructions are drawn from Ubuntu, miscellaneous sites, and my own experience.  Consolidated for ppc architecture.  Various Lubuntu and Ubuntu distributions worked in the past but have lost support or elegance, and Ubuntu MATE 16.04.2 LTS / Ubuntu MATE both work now in both elegance and function (with updates).